# Blazor (Server) and the async/await pattern

Tags: async-await, blazor, blazor-server-side

The [Introduction to ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0) article by Microsoft (Daniel Roth and Luke Latham) show examples of awaited calls in the Razor Code, *e.g.*

```
@code {
    private WeatherForecast[] forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

However, none of the examples suggest whether the razor pages should continue on the captured context, or not, *e.g.*

```
.ConfigureAwait(false);
or 
.ConfigureAwait(true);
```

Does Blazor have the concept of the UI Thread being the only thread able to update components?  What is considered "best practice" when calling awaited calls in the Page and/or in page components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does Blazor have the concept of the UI Thread being the only thread able to update components?

With Server-side Blazor: yes.
With Client-side there only is one thread (JavaScript) so, yes, kind of.

> What is considered "best practice" when calling awaited calls in the Page and/or in page components.

To *not* use any ConfigureAwait().

You are on a sync context that has an implicit default behaviour of  `ConfigureAwait(true)`.

ConfigureAwait() will only be useful when your create extra threads (with Task.Run()) but in general you shouldn't want that.